# Send Email Notification unable to work

Tags: email, notification

When I am trying to change the lead owner of a lead under my name and once I click on send email notification but do not receive any email. Why is my email notification checkbox not working?

Regards,
Kunal

Comment: In Production Instance or Sandbox and did you check Deliverability @kunal gupta

Comment: Hi@Pavan,Under Deliverability I can see the following: Access Level : All email, activate bounce management is checked,Enable compliance with standard email security mechanisms is checked and Notify sender when mass email completes is checked.

Comment: localize the issue by examining SFDC Email Logs to see if (a) SFDC sent the email and b) your email system received it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @kunal gupta You have to go to setup > Email administration > Deliverability >

For reference:

[image]

In options you have to change to All Email other wise your org can't send email to users after that you can test the Deliverability(optional is not needed).

May be this works for you.

Comment: Hi @pavan : It's already set to All email

Comment: You are doing this in sandbox or production Instance @kunal gupta